# MySQL displaying results

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me. Can anyone here tell me why the results from my database display the links like this?

```
 Art
 Art
 Art
 Art
 Music
 Music
 Music
 Music
 Drama
 Drama
 Drama
 Drama
 Medical
 Medical
 Medical
```

I would like to have the categories displayed like this,

```
Art
Music
Drama
Medical
```

...and this is the code I have in my `index.php`

```
<?php 

             $dbh=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root") or die ('Cannot connedt to the Database' .mysql_errno()); 
             mysql_select_db("books");


             $res = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY category ASC";
             $res_query = mysql_query($res) or die (mysql_error());
             $ra = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query);  

?>



     <?php do { ?>
       <p><a href="page.php?id=<?php echo $ra['id']; ?>"><?php echo $ra['category']; ?></a></p>
    <?php } while ($ra = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query))?>
```

...and this is the code I have in `page.php` which displays the results...

```
<?php 

$dbh=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root") or die ('Cannot connedt to the Database' .mysql_errno()); 
mysql_select_db("books");

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];
}else {
$id=1;
}
$res = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id=$id";
$res_query = mysql_query($res) or die (mysql_error());
$ra = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query);  

?>


<h1><?php echo $ra['category']; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $ra['author']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $ra['title']; ?></p>
```

below is my database I've created a for my book collection.

---

### id      | category  |   author   |  title

```
1       |Art        |   Author1  |      title1
2       |Art        |   Author2  |  title2
3       |Art        |   Author3  |  title3
4       |Art        |       Author4  |  title4
5       |Music          |   Author1  |  title1
6       |Music          |   Author2  |  title2
7       |Music          |   Author3  |  title3
8       |Music          |   Author4  |  title4
9       |Drama          |   Author1  |  title1
10      |Drama          |   Author2  |  title2
11      |Drama          |   Author3  |  title3
12      |Drama          |   Author4  |  title4
13      |Medical    |   Author1  |  title1
14      |Medical    |   Author2  |  title2
15      |Medical    |   Author3  |  title3
```

---

Comment: Do you want them grouped (as in: not see duplicates)? You might use `GROUP BY` then.

Comment: Yep, I tried that but it displays only one 'author' and 'title' instead of 'author1-4' 'title1-4'

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question. What is it you actually want  to achieve? Returning data as it is in your database (ex. Category / Author / Title)?

Comment: The 'index.php' displays all 'categories' as they are in the database. i.e; 'Art' is displayed 4 times, and 'Music' is displayed 4 times and so on...

Comment: And you _don't_ want them to be shown 4 times?

Comment: Yes, I do not want them to be shown 4 times.

Comment: I see you're using two queries for this. One to show the categories and the other one to show all the books. Why not use a query where you get the categories (`SELECT category FROM books GROUP BY category`) to build your category links?

Comment: Bro, I am new to PHP. Can you explain to me in details?

Comment: You want to have some links to your categories, and from your category page you want to select a book, right? That's 3 pages: One 'category' page, one 'category-specific' page and one 'book-specific' page. Create distinct MySQL queries for each page and you should be fine (category page: select only categories, category-specific page (book overview): select all information within a specific category, book-specific page: select all information from a single book.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. But I do not know how to do that. could you give me an example?

Comment: I'll create a simple example, hang on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to learn PHP and create a website for my library.

Comment: Okay, I added my answer. If I understand correctly, this works (atleast, it does for me).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Change the below line in index.php

```
$res = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY category ASC";
```

to

```
$res = "SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY category ORDER BY category ASC";
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=
Notice: Undefined index: page_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\books' at line 1

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY category' at line 1

Comment: yaa... change the order of order by and group by... see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have created a simple small example which should give you an idea of how to fix this. It's in no-way a best practice example (nor did I put really much time into it), but it does the trick.

This has been made to focus on **functionality**, not on performance (just showing you *a* way, not *the* way).

My tables in MySQL:

**Book**

```
ID  Name            Author              Description
1   Sample Book 1   Sample Author 1     Small description for book 1
2   Sample Book 2   Sample Author 2     Larger description for book 2 (BECAUSE WE EXTEND THIS BY SOME UNKONWN BLAH)
3   Sample Book 3   Sample Author 3     No description found for 3? Wrong! This is the description!
4   Sample Book 4   Sample Author 4     Description for book 4
5   Sample Book 5   Sample Author 5     Description for book 5
6   Sample Book 6   Sample Author 6     Description for book 6
```

**Category**

```
ID      name

1       art
2       music
3       drama
4       medical
```

**Category_Book (link table between them)**

```
ID  category_id   book_id
1   1             1
2   2             2
3   2             3
4   3             4
5   4             5
6   4             6
```

I then have three .php files, called *category-overview.php*(shows all categories), *book-overview.php*(shows all books within a specific category) and *book-view.php*(shows information about one specific book).

The code for these files:

**category-overview.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $dbh = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die("Can't connect.");
        mysql_select_db("books");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY name ASC";
        $execute = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $categories = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)) {
            $categories[] = $row;
        }


        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            ?>
            <p><a href="book_overview.php?category=<?php echo $category['name'] ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($category['name']) ?></a> </p> 


        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**book-overview.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
            $category = $_GET['category'];

            $dbh = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die("Can't connect.");
            mysql_select_db("books");

            $query = "SELECT * FROM book b WHERE b.id IN (SELECT book_id FROM category_book WHERE category_id = (SELECT id FROM category WHERE name = '$category'));";
            $execute = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            $books = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)) {
                $books[] = $row;
            }

            foreach ($books as $book) {
                echo '<b>Book Title:</b> ' . $book['title'] . '<br/>';
                echo '<b>Book Written By:</b> ' . $book['author'] . '<br/>';
                echo '<a href="book_view.php?id=' . $book['id'] . '">Read more about this book...</a><br/>';
                echo '<br/>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**book-view.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];

            $dbh = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die("Can't connect.");
            mysql_select_db("books");

            $query = "SELECT * FROM book b WHERE b.id = '$id';";
            $execute = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            $book;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)) {
                $book = $row;
            }

            if ($book !== null) {
                echo '<b>Book Title:</b> ' . $book['title'] . '<br/>';
                echo '<b>Book Written By:</b> ' . $book['author'] . '<br/>';
                echo '<p>' . $book['description'] . '</p><br/>';
                echo '<br/>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

How it works:

In category-overview, all I do is retrieve the categories and create the hyperlinks for them.

In book-overview I check for a category in the `$_GET` variable. If there is one, retrieve all books with that category id (by using the link table). I create the hyperlinks by the IDs gotten by retrieving all the book information.

In book-view you just do the same, but for one specific book (check for `$_GET`, if found, retrieve data for that specific book).

I hope it clears it up a bit on how it could/should work. If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do it and let you know.